# Is it possible to get the property type within a generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the type of an property from within a generic type:

```
export type TestType = {
    key1: string,
    key2: number,
    key3: Array<string>
};

const test:TestType = {
    key1: 'hello',
    key2: 56,
    key3: ['hi']
};


function getProperty<T> (obj:T, property:keyof T): T[typeof property]{
    return obj[property];
}

const thisVariableShouldBeAString:string = getProperty<TestType>(test, 'key1');
//thisVariableShouldBeAString has type "string | number | string[]" which is not "string"
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOM3NQXjgG8AoASAGthEBGALjmygEsA7AcwBpyrEAmBqwCuAWwBGwKN0rUAzAwCCUKAENEAHiZt2APhIBfANwkSAYwitsCLDDoZsuFHEKkZtBgHIAFsAA2viA9pXgE4AFYANmC5BgBtb2YPAF0DYxMAMyFWUxhmCzh2YBgABSgIFFgNNB04AAoIMQArO044MDKKpDpeCHT0AEoGNFikFF62jskkJNcoIqEoVjgGxtj28qnEJON9E3NLeBgvZkwANRUWFTFfYABlLwghXwATACFgBVuYFg46LQ5nAUiqUNpV1PYcHgdLUYDZWh5eDQPP1jAB6VFHE7nS7XO4PJ5vD5fH7sOBeFSYBB4OAAIn+pIAPnBhOJJHAmfTYkkaXAAO7HUxeOAnZkQeB077aGlAA)

But it does not work! thisVariableShouldBeAString ends up with an union types of all the properties within TestType

Doing `test['key1']` instead of `getProperty<TestType>(test, 'key1')` is not sufficient for my usecase.

Is it possible to properly type the getProperty function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another type parameter to `getProperty` that extends `keyof T`:

```
export type TestType = {
    key1: string,
    key2: number,
    key3: Array<string>
};

const test: TestType = {
    key1: 'hello',
    key2: 56,
    key3: ['hi']
};


function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, property: K): T[K] {
    return obj[property];
}

const thisVariableShouldBeAString = getProperty(test, 'key1');
```